# Where to specify NSShowNonLocalizedStrings in MonoDevelop / MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, locale

I have found this article:
http://jomnius.blogspot.de/2011/06/how-to-find-unlocalized-strings.html

It describes how to specify `NSShowNonLocalizedStrings` in your app to make the console print out untranslated locale.
Where and how do I have to specify this option in MonoDevelop?